# After registering SpringBeanFacesELResolver, @Named @RequestScoped behaves like Spring singleton

Tags: spring, jsf-2, scope

I am creating new JSF 2.2 application and found this issue:

I have:
1) EL Resolver

```
 <application>
    <locale-config>
        <default-locale>ru</default-locale>
    </locale-config>
    <resource-bundle>
        <base-name>i18n.messages</base-name>
        <var>msg</var>
    </resource-bundle>
    <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
    <!--<variable-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.WebApplicationContextVariableResolver</variable-resolver>-->
</application>
```

2) Faces Bean

```
@Named("SubscriberBalance")
@RequestScoped 
public class SubscriberBalance extends AbstractManagedBean {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -7018658511320101002L;
private SupportService supportService;
private SubscriberBalanceWrapper subscriberBalance;
private Long subscriberId;
private Integer subscriberType;
private Integer months;
```

3) Spring4+Hibernate4

And after that,my bean shares data between all users. It behaves like spring singleton. It seems like it ignore JSF scopes and process only Spring scopes. So @Scope("request") is working, but @RequestScope doesnt. How to do it correctly? And why it happening? Thank you

Comment: Spring doesn't do anything with CDI scopes (this isn't related to JSF). If you want something to be a JSF bean then let it be a JSF bean. Use `@ManagedBean` instead of `@Named`.

Comment: Thank you, but the issue is @RequestScope is just ignored, but @Scope("request") works. It behaves like a singleton. Why?

Comment: As stated spring doesn't do anything with CDI scopes... Hence adding `@RequestScope` or the others don't do a thing.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But @ManagedBean is obsolete. I love how easily CDI beans may inject other beans and etc. But I prefer to use Spring ecosystem. What should I do to use my JSF beans and inject there spring beans (services)?

Comment: The point is you aren't using CDI you are using Spring. The fact that you use the CDI annotations doesn't mean you are actually using CDI. The JSF annotations are still useable but if you prefer not to use them either use the spring annotations for scoping or provide your custom scope implementations which work with the CDI annotations.

Answer (score 2):

I think I figured out this issue and may be it will be helpful for someone.

So we have:

1) CDI - feature of Java EE 6

2) Spring framework

3) JSF

First of all, Spring never interact with CDI in my case. CDI @Named annotation is JSR 330 annotation. But since spring 3.0, Spring also scans those annotations. So that`s why in my case @Named works.

The second, @Named is full equivalent to @Component. So I could use @Component there as well.
@RequestScope and other JSF annotations will not work because its not JSF context, but Spring context. If we need to use JSF context, we need to use @ManagedBean, etc. 
@Scope annotation works because its Spring-managed bean, because I have package-scan enabled for my bean.

So approaches are:

1) Use pure JSF with @ManagedBean annotations. I dont prefer this way. Disadvantages are: poor DI integration, much handy work, etc

2) Use CDI. I dont like it as we have Spring

3) Use Spring everywhere. I love this way as it gives me one-way control on all parts of my system. I will not have to think about JSF specific annotations until I really need them.

So in JSF backend bean should be:

@Controller

@Scope(...)

Please see [this article](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-standard-annotations)
Thank you